# Trying to create a verification process for checksum files

Tags: batch-file, file-io, windows-7

I have two checksum files in two different locations on my network, I need to verify that they match one another and output `** UNVERIFIED **` if they do not. So what needs to be done is I need to read both files into a variable one at a time, then check the variables against one another for verification purposes.

What I've tried:

```
:verify_integrity
    set "verf_integrity_src_file=\\ROCIO-148084\c$\Users\z-perkins-thomas\Documents\bin\batch\verf"
    set "verf_integrity_dst_file=%cd%\docs\checksum.md5"
    pushd "%verf_integrity_src_file%"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set content_src=

    for /f "delims=" %%x in (%verf_integrity_src_file%\checksum.md5) do (set content_src=!content_src! %%x)

    endlocal
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set content_dst=

    for /f "delims=" %%y in (%verf_integrity_dst_file%) do (set content_dst=!content_dst! %%y)

    endlocal

    @echo %content_dst%==%content_src%
```

This will output nothing -> "=="

Secondly I tried something along the lines of this:

```
:verify_integrity
    set "verf_integrity_src_file=\\ROCIO-148084\c$\Users\z-perkins-thomas\Documents\bin\batch\verf"
    set "verf_integrity_dst_file=%cd%\docs\checksum.md5"
    pushd "%verf_integrity_src_file%"
    set verf_src=
    for /f "delims=" %%x in (%verf_integrity_src_file%\checksum.md5) do set verf_src=%verf_src% %%x
    set verf_dst=
    for /f "delims=" %%y in (%verf_integrity_dst_file%) do set verf_dst=%verf_dst% %%y
    @echo %verf_src%
    goto :verify_argv
```

This will output the last line in the checksum file ->  22534f499bc7755d58412327853c8d9a *./zip-archive/utilis0.1.zip

So my question is this, how can I read both files into memory, and verify if they match one another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to just check if two files are identical, use [fc](https://ss64.com/nt/fc.html):

If you are sure, both files exist, it's as easy as:

```
fc "file1.ext" "file2.ext" >nul || echo ** UNVERIFIED **
```

If not, explicitely check the `%errorlevel%`:

```
-1 Invalid syntax (e.g. only one file passed) 
0 The files are identical.
1 The files are different.
2 Cannot find at least one of the files.
```

Comment: Oooo I didn't even know that was a thing